# multiple solutions to a nonlinear problem in GAMS

Tags: nonlinear-programming, gams, global-optimality

Good afternoon, I have the following doubts

1. Is there a command in GAMS that lets me know when my problem has multiple optimal solutions?
2. Suppose my nonlinear optimization problem has multiple global solutions. By solving the model with GAMS I obtain a global optimal solution of that problem. The question is how to obtain a different global optimal solution without having to solve a new problem (like Magnanti-Wong for example).

Just to narrow down some ideas and attempts I made was through the magnanti Wong subproblem (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O4gCxZQxVEvMyfx_Bh7mR3ZIuN6XDxE_/view?usp=sharing) to obtain one of those optimal global solutions different from those obtained in a classical way, however this is very difficult and I am still doing tests.

Answer (score 4):

The global solver Baron can give you multiple solutions using the `numsol` option. For an example see: https://www.gams.com/latest/gamslib_ml/libhtml/gamslib_mhw4dxx.html.